# How to put an external link + the parameter

Tags: symfony, url, symfony4, sonata-admin

Currently, I would like to have redirected CV links to my AWS S3 bucket. I use Sonata Admin.

With the URL I am redirected on

```
 ->add('cvName', 'url', [
                'url' => "https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/*****/",
                'attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']
            ])
```

Without I am redirect on the CV name.

```
 ->add('cvName', 'url', [
                'attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']
            ])
```

I would like that when you click on the link, be redirected to the address "https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/*****/ + CVNAME"

Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `str_replace`:

```
url = str_replace('*****', CVNAME, "https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/*****/")
```

Comment: How I can use str_replace in this context?

Comment: 'url' => str_replace('*****', 'cvName', "https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/*****/")

Comment: cvName it's not replace by the name of the CV :/

Comment: I got https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/cvName but I want cvName is replace by the correct cvName

Comment: All user have a specifical cvName, this cvName is register in the user entities, you understand?

Comment: I believe this is the variable 'cvName'? If that is the case, just use it on `str_replace` instead `CVNAME`

Comment: I doesn't have variable cvName I don't know if you know how work sonata?